# Can't remove ceph xattrs on linux

Tags: linux, xattr, ceph

I had set xattrs for quota limits on CephFS

```
$ setfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes -v 1100000000  /mnt/cephfs/data/
```

I can get value of this attribute

```
$ getfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes /mnt/cephfs/data/
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/cephfs/data/
ceph.quota.max_bytes="1100000000"
```

But then I try to remove quota, I had

```
$ setfattr -x ceph.quota.max_bytes /mnt/cephfs/data/
setfattr: /mnt/cephfs/data/: No such attribute
```

How can I remove this xattr?

Answer (score 1):

The way to remove the quota is not to use `setfattr -x` but set the value to 0:

```
setfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes -v 0 /mnt/cephfs/data/
```

After the value has been set to 0 the attribute is not present anymore:

```
getfattr /mnt/cephfs/data/ -n ceph.quota.max_bytes
/mnt/cephfs/data/: ceph.quota.max_bytes: No such attribute
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephfs/quota/) for more information.

Comment: I know this way, but I need to remove attribute, not set to 0. Its optional attribute. Other optional attributes are removed without problem, but Ceph's are not. They have some limitations `getfattr -d` don't show ceph domain too. I need to exactly remove optional attr, may be by call syscalls or any dirty tricks

Comment: Did you read the docs? If you set the value to 0 the attribute is actually removed. If you run a `getfattr` on the path again it will show you "No such attribute"